# For loop with two variables in TCL

Tags: c, tcl

I want to transform the following c code to TCL.

```
int a[10],b[10];
int n=20

for (i=1,j=1; i<=n; i+=2,j++)
{
  b[j]=a[i];
}
```

I need to change this for loop to TCL, I don't want to use the foreach feature in TCL...
Does TCL for loop structure allow two loop variables???

Comment: That's not the real code, is it?  Reading from past the end of an array is a bad idea.

Comment: that is not the real code, it is something like assigning the first element in a[] to b[], neglecting the second element of a[] and assigning the third element of a[] again to b[], omitting the adjacent element of a[] and assigning it to b[].

Comment: it is something similar to assigning  odd positions of a[] to b[].

Comment: You don't really need two loop variables then.  `j` and `2*j+1` are the same as what you have there, right?

Comment: you mean to say that there is no need for another array b[]??

Comment: `b` is fine.  I'm saying you don't need `i`.

Comment: The natural method in Tcl is to use `foreach`, but the first and third parameters to `for` are just normal scripts — with normal behavior of `\n` and `;` — that are run at the right time...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you seen the [discussion here](http://wiki.tcl.tk/963):

```
  set n 6
  for {
              set  i     1
              set  j     1
          } {
              $i < $n
          } {
              incr i
              incr j
          } {
              puts "$i $j"
   }
```

Comment: +1. You could use semicolons instead of newlines for a more compact look: `for {set i 1; set j 1} {$i < $n} {incr i; incr j} {...}`

Answer (score 3):

This doesn't achieve exactly what you're looking for, but considering you're coming from C where you need to have the target array to start with... it's possible it might achieve your actual goal.

The `foreach` loop can take, as the storage variable, a list of names. Each names gets one of the values from the input list. As such, you can use it to iterate over multiple values from the input list each time:

```
set result {}
foreach {x1 x2} {1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20} {
    lappend result $x1
}
puts $result
# 1 3 5 7 9 11 13 15 17 19
```

Totally unrelated to your problem, but also nice, is that it can take multiple variable names and lists, too:

```
set result {}
foreach {a1 a2} {1 2 3 4 5 6} b {A B C} {
    lappend result $a1 $b $a2 -
}
puts $result
# 1 A 2 - 3 B 4 - 5 C 6
```